# fsockopen not working whit FastCGI (PHP)

Tags: php, centos, fastcgi, fsockopen

I have a php question about fsockopen

Server:

VPS CentOS 6.3 (Final) PLESK 11

Problem:

If i use FastCGI the function fsockopen is not working. 
I get: Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:80 (Permission denied)

If i edit the website (for testing) in plesk 11 and set it to apache it works.

I can't find the fix for this problem. Somebody has a clue?

Answer (score 8):

Disable selinux or add a new rule to let apache open remote connections

to add a rule use

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

to disable selinux or set it in permissive mode edit your

```
/etc/selinux/config
```